# How to detect when DVD drive drawer opens

Tags: ubuntu, dvd

I have been challenged to write a script to close my unbutu dvd drive when it opens, and to close it I just use the command

```
eject -t
```

but I am unable to find any documentation on how to detect when the drive opens....

Is there anyway to detect when the DVD drive drawer opens in ubuntu?

Comment: only if the device has a function that tells you that the drive is open, and you can access that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is basically contained [here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl/cdrom.txt). In */usr/include/linux/cdrom.h* you will find all *ioctl()* for the cdrom,

```
#define CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS      0x5326  /* Get tray position, etc. */
```

A snippet of code returning this for you is:

```
 int slot;
 ioctl(fd, CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS, slot);

 switch(slot) {
    case CDS_NO_INFO: ... break;
    case CDS_NO_DISC: ... break;
    case CDS_TRAY_OPEN: ... break;
    case CDS_DRIVE_NOT_READY: ... break;
    case CDS_DISC_OK: ... break;
    default: /* something else, whichever you like */
 }
```

The key point is, of course, CDS_TRAY_OPEN.

Comment: @Sickest it's the output of man <command>